# how to get handlebar template name using helper?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to get handlebarjs template name using handlebar helper, how to do it? thanks! for example,
give:
a.hbs

```
<p>hello</p>
{{fileName}}
```

I want:
a.html

> hello a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easy and the safe way, is to get the template of the current view.
And get your name, based in the identity, using `Ember.TEMPLATES`.

Since the `TEMPLATES` structure is `{ templateName: compiledTemplate }`.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('filename', function(options) {  
  var template = options.data.view.get('template');
  for (var templateName in Ember.TEMPLATES) {
    if (Ember.TEMPLATES[templateName] === template) {
      return templateName;
    }
  }
});
```

Live demo http://jsbin.com/ucanam/674/edit

Comment: Thanks! Very appriciate!